# how to select rows whose key is in a column of another table?

Tags: mysql

I hava two tables A and B.The primary key of A is id.There is a columns called ids in B which is a varchar type.The value of ids is a string separated by commas,like '1,2,3'.
Then how to select rows in A who's id is in the ids of B?
for example,the content of the two tables are:

```
    A
id  name
1    jack
2    rose

    B
id     ids
1       1,2
2       1
```

I want to select jack and rose if B.id = 1.
how should I do this in mysql?

Comment: is there any reason why you haven't just got a 1:n or n:n table relationship?

Comment: the circumstances to insert a row in B like this:one will choose many people at a time(inclued in A),so if a make a 1:n relationship I will do many inserts,I save id as a string in order to reduce the time of insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    a.name
FROM
a
INNER JOIN b
    ON (FIND_IN_SET(a.id,b.ids) > 0)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set